# Turn off shadow when hovering disabled button only

Tags: css, button, fluent-design, fluent-kit

I am creating buttons using [Bootstrap button generator](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/components/button/). Those are fluent design buttons and I noticed that when `:disabled` the button still casts shadow on `:hover`.

My questions:

1. How do I stop the shadow when button is disabled?
2. Is it OK to do that? It *seems* to be good choice to me, but is it somewhere documented for Fluent Design buttons?

I tried:

```
.btn.disabled:hover { box-shadow: none; }
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: you used a dot instead of a colon

Comment: to clarify over what @Pete said, use `.btn:disabled:hover` instead of `.btn.disabled:hover`

Comment: Thank you @Pete, it is what helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the work, you just forgot to use a colon `:` for `:disabled` instead of dot `.` which means CSS pseudo class.

```css
.btn:disabled:hover{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `pointer-events:none` property to button disable CSS.

Because, default the button hover is written like that, we should add a custom CSS like this.

```
.btn:disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
}

/*****************OR***************************/

.btn:disabled {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It somehow looks like a hack to me and I like the first solution much better. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @Pete, in order for your code to work, you need to use [CSS special state selector, `:disabled`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp) instead of the `.disabled` class.

```
.btn:disabled { box-shadow: none; }
```

Addressing the second question, is it Fluent Design specific? I don't believe it is - you will not find any plain guidelines for doing things with Fluent Design as of now (July 2018), only [some general idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/fluent-design-system/).

---

On the side, we will add the same styling to the Fluent Kit library itself, as it is oversight on our side, so with next releases you won't see shadow on the mentioned, disabled [Bootstrap buttons](https://nespero.com/fluent/jquery/docs/components/button/).

Comment: Thank you for the w3schools link, it helps. Next time I'll try contacting you directly about small thing like this one, is it OK?

Comment: I think I've got you one better - we have the whole subject covered on [our Fluent Kit support page](https://nespero.com/support/) - it says both when to use StackOverflow network and when to contact us directly. I hope it helps.